# Unnest in R conditional on the cell's content

Tags: r, nested, unnest

The [main dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7bSB.png) has a column "passings". It is the only nested variable in the main dataframe. Inside it, there are dataframes [(an example a nested cell)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYsTT.png). In the nested cells, the number of rows varies, yet the number of columns is the same. The columns names are "date" and "title". What I need is to **grab a respective date** and put it in the main dataframe as a new variable **if** title is "Закон прийнято" ("A passed law" - translation).

I'm a newbie in coding. 
I will appreciate your help!

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7bSB.png)
[an example of a dataframe within a nested cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYsTT.png)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. (Pictures of data are not reproducible)

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Next time, I will do this. This time, I did not really knew how to do that. The reproducible example is posted below by @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option where we loop over the 'passings' `list` column with `map` (based on the image, it would be a `list` of 2 column `data.frame`), `filter` the rows where the 'title' is "Закон прийнято" (assuming only a single value per row) and `pull` the 'date' column to create a new column 'date' in the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(date = map_chr(passings, ~ .x %>%
                                       filter(title == "Закон прийнято") %>%
                                       pull(date)))

#   id passed                                     passings       date
#1 54949   TRUE 2015-06-10, 2015-06-08, abcb, Закон прийнято 2015-06-08
#2 55009   TRUE  2015-06-10, 2015-09-08, bcb, Закон прийнято 2015-09-08
```

NOTE: It works as expected.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(54949, 55009), passed = c(TRUE, TRUE), 
    passings = list(structure(list(date = c("2015-06-10", "2015-06-08"
    ), title = c("abcb", "Закон прийнято")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)), structure(list(date = c("2015-06-10", "2015-09-08"
    ), title = c("bcb", "Закон прийнято")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I'm so grateful! Now, I'll try to understand how it actually works.

Comment: @YuliiaZhaha Thank you.  T